# can we change the list in a nested tuple to tuple

Tags: python-2.7, list, tuples

```
t = (1,2,3,4,5,6,[7,8])

type(t[6])
<type 'list'>

tuple(t[6])
(7, 8)

type(tuple(t[6]))
<type 'tuple'>
```

I want to reflect this change in the tuple "t"

How can I change this to `t = (1,2,3,4,5,6,(7,8))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, you will need to construct a new tuple, e.g. change `t` to a mutable type `list` update the value and convert back to a `tuple`:

```
>>> x = list(t)
>>> x[6] = tuple(x[6])
>>> tuple(x)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, (7, 8))
```